# Setting minimum size for component in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to set the minimum size of a component instead of just the preferred size?

I am currently setting the preferred size by overriding the `calcPreferredSize` method on the component, but the layout shrinks it to an unknown minimum regardless of the preferred size during certain scenarios.

I am using code, not the UI builder.

Comment: you can set different layouts using setLayout. 
Can you post your codes?

Answer (score 0):

No, we don't have a way to do that.

We didn't copy the minimum/maximum concepts from AWT/Swing since those never made sense there either and were used in different ways by the layouts. If a component is in a situation where it can't fit we have a problem regardless of the minimum value. You need to place it in a scrollable Y container or give it more space.

Preferred size is a hint the eventual determination of size is done by the layout manager logic.

If you have a specific example of something that misbehaves in terms of layout I'd be happy to help with that.